# About one of the conditions of 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

R = {A, B, C, D}
functional dependencies F = {A -> B, B -> C, C -> D}

After processing of making it 3NF:
we get {{A,B}, {B,C}, {C,D}}

Let's say `X -> A` represents each functional dependency.

`X` means left hand side and `A` means right hand side.

My main question is the second condition of 3NF--`X is a superkey`.

So `X` is a superkey of what?

of `R = {A, B, C, D}` or of each relation, `{A,B}, {B,C} and {C,D}`, in 3NF?

For example, `B` is a superkey also a candidate key of `{B,C}` but not a superkey or candidate key of `R = {A, B, C, D}`.

I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation is in 3NF if, for every `X -> A` in that relation, one of these conditions hold:

- `X` contains `A` (that is, `X -> A` is trivial functional dependency), or
- `X` is a superkey, or
- Every element of `A-X`, the set difference between `A` and `X`, is a prime attribute.

In the case of `R = {A, B, C, D}`, we have an FD `B -> C` such that:

- `B` doesn't contain `C`, and
- `B` isn't a superkey of `R`, and
- `C` isn't a prime attribute of `R`.

Therefore `R` isn't in 3NF.

However, if we look at `R1 = {B, C}` in which `B -> C`, then:

- `B` doesn't contain `C`, and
- `B` **is** a superkey of `R1`, and
- `C` isn't a prime attribute of `R1`.

Therefore `R1` is in 3NF.

Comment: so in my example `R = {A, B, C, D}` and `F = {A -> B, B -> C, C -> D}`, it is not in 3NF right? Since `B -> C` does not match any condition of 3NF and `C -> D` neither.

Comment: If I want it to in 3NF each FD in F has to satisfy at least one of the conditions. Am I correct?

Comment: Ok! I totally got it! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

When we say "normalize R to xNF" we mean "replace R by some projections/components that are each in xNF". R is gone; it's equal to the join of the components. Each *component* must meet the conditions of xNF using its own FDs, superkeys, CKs, etc.